# Running a python method or script clicking a html text link (Qtextbrowser)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, qtextbrowser

There are similar posts to this question but none match what I need.

In a QtextBrowser I have several text links. On clicking one of them, I need to capture  this string and send it as parameter to a python method in order to display another information.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I do not understand you, you could show an example and what you hope to obtain based on that example. Please take the time to review the [tour] and [ask]

Comment: the text you indicate in the image has an associated url, that is, you have used h-ref, please provide a [mcve] so we will save time and confusion.

Comment: edit your question and add your code there, also it would be great to share an example of xlista